# android sqlite items

Tags: android, sqlite, items

hi to all i have this android sqlite code to read all the titles from a table and this code is in the DBHelper.java

```
//---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_BOOK,
                KEY_AUTHOR,
                KEY_EDITION,    
                KEY_YEAR,
                 KEY_RETURNDATE}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
```

and this is the code in my main app.....

```
//---get all titles---
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
                DisplayTitle(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

my question is that i want to get for example the returendate so i can compare it to the current time and based on that i will make an action

so can i read it ....buffer[5] and compare it....???

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your return date is a string, you can use the following in your DisplayTitle(cursor c) :

```
String returnDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_RETURNDATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doWork()
    {
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if(c==null)
            return;


        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {

          String key= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(5)));
          //and now you can put the condition to compare current time with key

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_RETURNDATE));`as rajath said, and don't forget to close your Cursor after your loop if you don't need it any more: `c.close();` else you will have a memory leak.